# Automatically send messages as current user in discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm new to discord.js but I would like to understand. Is it possible to achieve a functionality that would send message as my current user?

I mean for example I'm normal user on a discord server and I want to send randomly some jokes every day once. But this should happen from my current user, which has the discord name.

I know I can have a bot created and registered, but this is another approach I think.

My questions are: Is this achievable with discord.js or not really? Is this functionality achiavable at all? And where do I begin?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a "self-bot", and is against the Terms of Service. As such, it is not supported.
Discord has made an [announcement regarding self-bots](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-) before.

Here is a relevant excerpt:

> Automating normal user accounts (generally called "self-bots") outside
> of the OAuth2/bot API is forbidden, and can result in an account
> termination if found.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. It's just like making a discord BOT. But rather than making a bot application and using its token, you just use YOUR token.

This is purely for **educational purposes only**, and you shouldn't use it for anything else. Everything is possible, especially with discord.js.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you very much, indeed it is for educational purposes, so I totally don't understand why people dislike the my question, it is a bit sad. I've never did any bots with discord, but I want to try ... don't know if I will succeed tho

Comment: Friend, I just wanted to try something out for educational purposes, and I've tried with my token, but it says 'invalid token', I took basically the first code from the discordjs guide, which is very simple, just to login in => client.login(token); (i found the token I'm using, but it says it is invalid) ... any idea?